# Is the ratio of heat transfers always given by the same function?

Tags: thermodynamics

In deriving the thermodynamic temperature scale, it uses the concept that heat transfer between two reservoirs is the function of the reservoirs' temperatures. i.e. $\frac{Q_1}{Q_2}=Φ(T_1,T_2)$. And then further express that $Φ(T_1,T_2)=\frac{ψ(T_1)}{ψ(T_2)}$.

Is it a hidden assumption that the function $Φ$ doesn't change its form for different temperatures? i.e. for different reservoirs we just plug in different temperatures $Φ(T_1,T_2)$, $Φ(T_3,T_4)$ but it can never be some other functions (say $f(T_3,T_4)$, $g(T_5,T_6)$, etc.) for different temperatures. Why?

Comment: Hi Kelvin; I removed your second question because each post should only consist of one question. I'd encourage you to post that second question separately.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written it for a given and apparently fixed by your assumption $T_1$ and $T_2$ there is a $Φ(T_1,T_2)=ψ(T_1)/ψ(T_2)$. Of course for any given ratio of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ one can say so as that is just *a* number but what Kelvin proved was that this ratio changes in a particular manner under the underlying assumption that it *may depend only on the two temperatures*. This is the crucial assumption. As one varies the temperatures the ratio of the absorbed and rejected heat must satisfy a compatibility criterion when one uses a 3rd intermediary heat sink and source. Now then it follows from simple continuity argument that the two-variable function $\Phi$ must be decomposable as a ratio of single variable functions. Fermi describes this very clearly, see page 40 in http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks13/1305021p.pdf